# Utilizar agregador do LINQ dinamicamente

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, reflexão

Estou tentado criar uma função para utilizar funções agregadoras do Linq (sum, average, count) e não estou tendo sucesso. Tenho o código a seguir:

```
    private double AgreggateDynamic<T>(IEnumerable<T> list, string propertyName, string func)
    {            
        //Converter o "array" para uma lista não resolveu
        //IEnumerable<T> listEnum = list.ToList();
        Type enumerableType = typeof(Enumerable);

        MethodInfo sumMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods().First(
            m => m.Name == func
                && m.IsGenericMethod);

        MethodInfo generic = sumMethod.MakeGenericMethod(enumerableType);

        Func<T, double> expression = x => Convert.ToDouble(x.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(x, null));            
        object[] parametersArray = new object[] { list, expression };

        return Convert.ToDouble(generic.Invoke(null, parametersArray));
    }

    AgreggateDynamic(list, "FooValue", "Sum");
```

Quando executo este trecho de código, a linha `return Convert.ToDouble(generic.Invoke(null, parametersArray));`, tenho o seguinte erro.

> O objeto de tipo 'Manager.Business.Tests.Foo[]' não pode ser convertido no tipo 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Linq.Enumerable]'.

Alguma ideia do que posso fazer?

Comment: Pela mensagem de erro, o problema ocorre por você estar enviando um array como parametro, ao invés de algo que implemente a interface IEnumerable(uma lista por exemplo).
Tente mudar esse array para uma lista e verifique se o erro permanece.

Comment: Já tentei isso. Algo como IEnumerable<T> listEnum = list.ToList();, e retorna o mesmo erro.

Comment: Eu não entendi qual a ideia de fazer isso.

Comment: Bem, a ideia é poder configurar em banco de dados algumas consultas que serão transformadas em gráficos, de forma dinâmica, de fontes de dados que não tenho models (procedures, webapi). E eu defino em tudo que é necessário pra fazer group bys, agregações e outros. Nesse caso, estou gerando uma agregação de forma dinâmica para gerar uma query.

Comment: Precisa de tudo isso? Eu faria mais simples.

Comment: Sim, preciso, infelizmente.

Comment: Preciso de um exemplo de `list` para montar um Fiddle para você.

Comment: Já tentou o `.ToEnumerable();` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Veja se essa solução atende sua necessidade:

```
public static double AgreggateDynamic<T>(IEnumerable<T> list, string propertyName, string func)
{
    Func<T, double> expression = x => Convert.ToDouble(x.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(x, null));

    switch (func.ToLower())
    {
        case "sum": return list.Sum(expression);
        case "average": return list.Average(expression);
        case "count": return list.Count();
        default:
            return 0;
    }
}


static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var list = new []
    {
        new { FooValue = 512313, FooValue2 = 5123 },
        new { FooValue = 512313, FooValue2 = 5123 },
        new { FooValue = 512313, FooValue2 = 5123 },
        new { FooValue = 512313, FooValue2 = 5123 },
    };

    Console.WriteLine("Sum: " + AgreggateDynamic(list, "FooValue", "Sum"));
    Console.WriteLine("Average: " + AgreggateDynamic(list, "FooValue", "Average"));
    Console.WriteLine("Count: " + AgreggateDynamic(list, "FooValue", "Count"));
}
```